# Can not create a new project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to open a new C++ project in Visual Studio(2012) but every time I create a new project this error pops up:

```
System.Collections.Generic.RandomizedStringEqualityComparer is not a 
GenericTypeDefiniton. MakeGenericType may only be called on a type for which 
Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.
```

I've already changed the project path and restarted visual studio several times but no result.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKqZK.jpg)

Comment: You forgot to mention which version of Visual Studio you are using. The command Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio will show you this in formation. Please make that clear in your question.

Comment: I would first try and reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry it's Visual Studio 2012,

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall or c++ compiler path was not set

Set Compiler Path or RunAsAdministrator

**Now add the Compiler directory to your path:**

1. Open the Control Panel (Start > Settings > Control Panel) and double-click the System program.
2. Click change settings links to open System Properties dialog.
3. Select the Advanced tab and click Environment Variables.
4. In the System Variables panel of the Environment Variables dialog, select the Path variable and click Edit.

**Default Path of Compiler**

Windows 7

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\VC\Bin\cl.exe
```

Windows XP

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\VC\Bin\cl.exe
```